# PHP 7 showing error on CodeIgniter v2

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, php-7

I have an application build on CI v.2. It works fine on PHP 5.6 but on localhost XAMPP with PHP v7, I am getting the following error:

```
    Severity: Warning

Message: Declaration of Home::index() should be compatible with MY_Controller_Admin::index($dt_params = Array)

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 0
```

Can someone help how to fix this ?

Comment: code of home.php page ?? plzz

Comment: Self explanatory error

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html#constructors